# Type A is not assignable to type B

Tags: typescript

I have a TSV file that I want to convert to an array of objects, and this is my code for it:

## The code

```
const handleFileConversion = (
  data: string, // the TSV file as text
  delimiter: string // "\t", a tab
): ParameterType[] => {
  const headers = data.slice(0, data.indexOf('\n')).split(delimiter);
  const rows = data.slice(data.indexOf('\n') + 1).split('\n');

  const headings = headers.map((header) => header.replace('\r', ''));

  const arr = rows.map((row) => {
    const values = row.split(delimiter);
    const parameter: ReducerObject = headings.reduce(reducerFunction(values), {});
    return parameter;
  });

  return arr;
};

const reducerFunction =
  (values: string[]) =>
  (object: object, header: string, index: number) => {
    if (header === 'factor') {
      const factors = values[index].split(';').map((num) => Number(num));
      object[header] = factors;
    } else {
      object[header] = values[index].replace('\r', '');
    }
    return object;
  };

type ReducerObject = {
  [key: string]: string | number[] | number;
};

type FlatRateOrPricePerPageType = {
  flatRate: number
  pricePerPage: ""
} | {
  flatRate: ""
  pricePerPage: number
};

export type ParameterType = {
  name: string,
  label: string,
  factor: [number, number, number, number],
  type: "checkbox" | "range" | "textField",
} & FlatRateOrPricePerPageType;
```

## The error

```
Type 'ReducerObject[]' is not assignable to type 'ParameterType[]'.
  Type 'ReducerObject' is not assignable to type 'ParameterType'.
    Type 'ReducerObject' is not assignable to type '{ name: string; label: string; factor: [number, number, number, number]; type: "checkbox" | "range" | "textField"; } & { flatRate: ""; pricePerPage: number; }'.
      Type 'ReducerObject' is missing the following properties from type '{ name: string; label: string; factor: [number, number, number, number]; type: "checkbox" | "range" | "textField"; }': name, label, factor, type  TS2322

    50 |   });
    51 | 
  > 52 |   return arr;
       |   ^
    53 | };
    54 | 
    55 | const reducerFunction =
```

I understand that it tells me, that the `RecuderObject` is missing four keys, but I am adding them with the function. And if I were to use `ParamaterType` instead of `ReducerObject` like so:

```
const parameter: ParameterType = headings.reduce(reducerFunction(values), {});
```

I get the following error:

```
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ParameterType'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type '{ name: string; label: string; factor: [number, number, number, number]; type: "checkbox" | "range" | "textField"; } & { flatRate: ""; pricePerPage: number; }'.
    Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type '{ name: string; label: string; factor: [number, number, number, number]; type: "checkbox" | "range" | "textField"; }': name, label, factor, type  TS2322

    46 |   const arr = rows.map((row) => {
    47 |     const values = row.split(delimiter);
  > 48 |     const parameter: ParameterType = headings.reduce(reducerFunction(values), {});
       |           ^
    49 |     return parameter;
    50 |   });
    51 |
```

And adding this as the second argument to the `.reduce()` doesn't fix it either:

```js
{
      name: '',
      label: '',
      factor: [0, 0, 0, 0],
      type: '',
}
```

Comment: The type `ReducerObject` is "larger" than the type `ParameterType`. There are values of type `ReducerObject` that do not match the type `ParameterType`.

Comment: @axiac how is it larger? The only difference I can see is that `ReducerObject` has `[key: string]`, but otherwise it uses a similar structure.

Comment: `{ foo: "bar" }` belongs to the type `ReducerObject` but it does not belong to the type `ParameterType`. Check it on the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShAmBXAxhATgeQEYCsLOCgF4oBvAKCigG0BrCEALigGdg0BLAOwHMBdZm068oAHyhdEAWyzpqfMROmy0AbnIBfdeVCQoAMQA2AQ2AxTEDGgAKnVNfTXjPCABVw0EhSoAzE2YtmSRl0SigwOwgHG2cIZgAieM1Fbyg-U3NgOKhEsIiOe0dYoOVQrXIdDygnNGMpCCy0dz0vMK467KFuHgAaMJNZQ0F2br7fYwIAezRmamCVHqUQtEX59FXStD4xqF1s+OQAC3xaLEmAD3jFeNreCCvxeKzz4H0OCEN4eL6NKAAyAz+TKWGyRaJOFzNCDacjISZcNhQYzMOBIVCYXD4QheNKTSYJLDGNBXcpwhGELDMGodRpQ4hkXH4nKE4lQcpAA).

Comment: Right, but the function will return what `ParameterType` will be.

Comment: @Mähnenwolf "The only difference I can see is that `ReducerObject` has `[key: string]`", that is a HUGE difference in set size. Lets say we have `{ a: any }` and `{ a: any; [key: string]: any }`, the first type contain all object that have exactly only 1 key, and that key is the string `a`. The second type contains all objects that have at least 1 key (the key `a`), however they can have any number of other keys. Meaning that the second type is infinitely larger than the first type, and the second type contains the first type.